# websearch_to_tsquery with optional words

Tags: postgresql

When I use websearch_to_tsquery and search for something like where
`to_tsvector('english', description) @@ websearch_to_tsquery('virtual reality')`
I get plenty of results.  when I add a word that doesn't exist anywhere in the description it gets back 0 such as `where to_tsvector('english', description) @@ websearch_to_tsquery('virtual reality fsdfasjkwnejkfb')`

How can I get the results of the closest matches vs all words matching?

Comment: The same problem I encountered with the to_tsquery function and ts_rank_cd.

Answer (score 0):

So after trying for quite some time I discovered that in my case the `to_tsquery`  function needed the config parameter in order to return a value other than 0 when there was clearly a closer match.

[The function definition from Postgresql:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/textsearch-controls.html)

```
to_tsquery([ config regconfig, ] querytext text) returns tsquery
```

How I ended up using it:

```
select ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english', 'ring the police'), to_tsquery('english', 'police'))
select ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english', 'ring the police'), to_tsquery('english', 'police | xyzz'))
```

both functions above return `0.1` while the following returns 0

```
select ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english', 'ring the police'), to_tsquery('police'))
```

I am pretty sure that's what's missing in your case too